How to log request URI and body along with route in Spring Cloud Gateway?
I'm working on a Spring Cloud Gateway project and I need to log the incoming request URI, body, and associated route using a GlobalFilter. Is there a recommended approach to achieve this?
I've explored various options, including implementing a custom GlobalFilter, but I'm facing difficulties in logging the route along with the request URI and body. Here's my current implementation:
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GlobalFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.AbstractGatewayFilterFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

@Component
public class LoggingFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<Object> {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoggingFilter.class.getName());

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Object config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
            ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();

            // Logging request URI
            logger.info("Incoming request URI: " + request.getURI());

            // Logging request body for POST and PUT requests
            if (request.getMethodValue().equalsIgnoreCase("POST") || request.getMethodValue().equalsIgnoreCase("PUT")) {
                return exchange.getRequest().getBody()
                        .flatMap(body -> {
                            String requestBody = bufferToString(body);
                            logger.info("Request body: " + requestBody);
                            return chain.filter(exchange);
                        });
            }

            return chain.filter(exchange);
        };
    }

    private String bufferToString(DataBuffer dataBuffer) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
        dataBuffer.read(bytes);
        return new String(bytes);
    }
}


‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍@Slf4j
public class GatewayRequestLoggingFilter implements GlobalFilter, Ordered {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        // Log request body for POST and PUT requests
        if (exchange.getRequest().getMethodValue().equalsIgnoreCase(HttpMethod.POST) ||
                exchange.getRequest().getMethodValue().equalsIgnoreCase(HttpMethod.PUT)) {
            return exchange.getRequest().getBody()
                    .map(dataBuffer -> {
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
                        dataBuffer.read(bytes);
                        String requestBody = new String(bytes);
                        log.info("Incoming request URI: {} with body: {}", exchange.getRequest().getURI(), requestBody);
                        return exchange;
                    }).then(chain.filter(exchange));// Return Mono<Void>
        }
        return chain.filter(exchange);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return 1;
    }
}

